# Why does OpensSSL's EVP_BytesToKey derive an IV as well as the key?

Tags: cryptography, openssl

In OpenSSL EVP_BytesToKey() can be used for key derivation from a password, hash, and a number of cycles.  That all makes perfect sense.  The function also can take in a cipher type and salt, and output an IV at the same time.  Here's the signature from the Man page:

```
int EVP_BytesToKey(const EVP_CIPHER *type, const EVP_MD *md,
                const unsigned char *salt,
                const unsigned char *data, int datal, int count,
                unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv);
```

Under what assumed use case is this secure, or more secure?

As far as I know, in the vast majority of cases an IV or nonce should be unique for each message, but doesn't need to be secret.  It looks like an IV is being encrypted or just stretched here.  If you have the ability to generate an appropriate salt value why not just generate an IV and include that in the header of your message?

Is the assumption that you're working in an environment without access to a high quality PRNG (maybe because you're operating cross platform with just the standard libraries and OpenSSL) and need to stretch your RNG as well as your password?

Or, in the case of a null salt, is it just assumed that most messages will use unique passwords so no effort to have unique IVs needs to be taken?  In this use case the output file would probably be raw cyphertext.

Comment: Possibly related:  In openssl v1.1.1 and higher, `openssl enc` derives the encryption key and the IV from the password (and a random salt) using a pbkdf2 function.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption for more info.

Comment: Only Eric knows for sure, but my guess **probably because that's what PKCS#5 v1 did**, and PKCS#5 v2 wasn't yet published when he created this. Note `enc` uses this for both key and IV, but 'traditional' (pre-PKCS8) PEM key files use it only for key and put a random value used for _both_ IV and salt in the file header; see the (shared) man page for PEM_write_$anykeytype .

Comment: Yeah PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC() seemed to have mostly the same signature but I didn't notice that it didn't output an IV.  So I guess generating the IV was part of the old standard, and now a fully-random IV is preferred and the salt is just there to add a nonce to the process of PBKDF2.  So both salt and IV should be sent/stored with the cyphertext?

Comment: in a sense this makes the IV unpredictable (a requirement for CBC) and it doesn't need to be transmitted. But yeah, with a randomized key there is no real need for a randomized IV. But I guess setting it doesn't hurt either, less to explain to reviewers / auditors etc.